# Set C# variable as a Select from database

Tags: c#, mysql, string, variables

How would I take info stored in a Select method and transfer it to a string? I'm trying to get the max value from the match_id column and get its value from command.CommandText into the matchCode string. Where would I go from here?

```
    string connectString = "Server=myServer;Database=myDB;Uid=myUser;Pwd=myPass;";
    string matchCode = "";
    MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectString);
    MySqlCommand command = connect.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(VAL(match_id)) FROM `data`";

    try
    {
       connect.Open();
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       matchCode = "??";
       connect.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
```

I'm new to C#, as it's like my fourth day trying it out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: matchCode = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery()` is a problem: you're telling it you don't want a result. You want `ExecuteScalar()` - that returns an object containing the first value in the first row of your resultset.

Comment: Please don't edit your question and implement the answer you got - people reading later won't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ExecuteNonQuery()` method is for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries. If you're just getting a single value back, use `ExecuteScalar()`. If you're getting a whole result set back, use `ExecuteReader()` or `Fill()` a DataSet object.

Also, there are some things that are idiomatic to C# that you should be doing:

```
public int GetMatchCode()
{
    //this could be loaded from config file or other source
    string connectString = "Server=myServer;Database=myDB;Uid=myUser;Pwd=myPass;";
    string sql = "SELECT MAX(VAL(match_id)) FROM `data`";
    using (var connect = new MySqlConnection(connectString))
    using (var command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connect))
    {
        connect.Open();
        var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
        if (result == DBNull.Value)
        {              
           //what you do here depends on your application
           // if it's impossible for the query to return NULL, you can even skip this
        }
        return (int)result;
    }
}
```

Some of the changes need explanation:

- I don't ever call `.Close()`. The `using` block takes care of that for me, even if an exception was thrown. The old code would have left the connection hanging if an exception occured.
- .Net developers tend to believe in very small methods. More than that, this method ought to be part of a class that has nothing but other simple public data access methods and maybe a few private helper methods or properties for abstracting common code in the class.
- There is no exception handling code here. If you have small methods that are part of a generic database access class, exception handling should be at higher level, where you are better positioned to make decisions about how to proceed.

Comment: +1 for managed `IDisposable` lifecycles with `using`. Cleans up the code much more as you can get a better grasp on object scope.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. One more thing though, how could this work if the data I was looking for was needed in Int form?

Comment: @Kragalon You'd have to change the return type to `int`, add a line to check for `DBNull`, and add a cast to int. I see now that you're using the Val() function, so I'll update the answer to show this.